# How to retrieve all OU of Active Directory in LDAP?

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

I am using ldap3. I want to retrieve all Organizational units of AD.
Here is my code

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SUBTREE, ALL
total_entries = 0

s = Server('172.30.1.197', port=636, use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL)
admin_username = "Administrator@naanal.local"
admin_password = "p@ssw0rd1"
c = Connection(s, user=admin_username, password=admin_password)
c.bind()
c.start_tls()

c.search(search_base = 'dc=naanal,dc=local',
         search_filter = '(objectClass=OrganizationalUnit)',
         search_scope = SUBTREE,
         paged_size = 5)

total_entries += len(c.response)

for entry in c.response:
    print(entry)

print('Total entries retrieved:', total_entries)
```

Output:

```
{'dn': u'OU=Domain Controllers,DC=naanal,DC=local', 'attributes': {}, 'raw_attributes': {}, 'type': 'searchResEntry'}
{'dn': u'OU=Police,DC=naanal,DC=local', 'attributes': {}, 'raw_attributes': {}, 'type': 'searchResEntry'}
{'dn': u'OU=dummy,DC=naanal,DC=local', 'attributes': {}, 'raw_attributes': {}, 'type': 'searchResEntry'}
{'type': 'searchResRef', 'uri': ['ldaps://ForestDnsZones.naanal.local/DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=naanal,DC=local']}
{'type': 'searchResRef', 'uri': ['ldaps://DomainDnsZones.naanal.local/DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=naanal,DC=local']}
{'type': 'searchResRef', 'uri': ['ldaps://naanal.local/CN=Configuration,DC=naanal,DC=local']}
('Total entries retrieved:', 6)
```

What is the last three entries in the result ? Why is it coming ?

Answer (score 0):

The last three entries look like referrals. According to the docs, referral chasing can be disabled. See here: http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/connections.html

```
c = Connection(s, user=admin_username, password=admin_password, auto_referrals=False)
```

Comment: Hmm...according to this it might not be avoidable: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python3-ldap/2014/000042.html . That seems kinda silly. There is also a `dereference_aliases` option for the searches, which might change the behavior, would try to set that to `DEREF_NEVER`.